# Heroku heroku-nextjs buildpack build failed

Tags: reactjs, heroku, next.js, buildpack

I have an app create in Heroku with a free account.

It's my first Nextjs app.  I have created a few react apps and deployed them successfully using the https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack buildpack,

I am attempting to use the https://github.com/mars/heroku-nextjs.git buildpack.  I continue to get the following error when pushing and attempting to build:

```
Enumerating objects: 695, done.
Counting objects: 100% (695/695), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (638/638), done.
Writing objects: 100% (695/695), 406.94 KiB | 1.78 MiB/s, done.
Total 695 (delta 388), reused 20 (delta 13)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote: -----> Using buildpack: https://github.com/mars/heroku-nextjs.git
remote: -----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://github.com/mars/heroku-nextjs.git
remote:        bash: /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/cc998aa50faebde1ea66717737aec22c884e4936/bin/detect: No such file or directory
remote:
remote:        More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote:  !
remote:  ! ## Warning - The same version of this code has already been built: b1006412ec2d412e7edaed795dcbceff02d98f82
remote:  !
remote:  ! We have detected that you have triggered a build from source code with version b1006412ec2d412e7edaed795dcbceff02d98f82
remote:  ! at least twice. One common cause of this behavior is attempting to deploy code from a different branch.
remote:  !
remote:  ! If you are developing on a branch and deploying via git you must run:
remote:  !
remote:  !     git push heroku <branchname>:main
remote:  !
remote:  ! This article goes into details on the behavior:
remote:  !   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/duplicate-build-version
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to gurnzapp-test.
```

I have read everything I can find online about this.  The most common error that is in the github issues is that people put package.json in a subdirectory.  My package.json is in the root.  My project is set up correctly as far as I can tell.

I have tried:

- pushing from the `main` branch directly to heroku's main branch.
- pushing from a local development branch in the `git push heroku development:main` format.
- removeing package-lock.json.
- Using another buildpack: https://github.com/ryanbahniuk/nextjs-buildpack.git

I'm at a loss as to why I'd have issues building.  Any help would be amazing :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote: -----> Using buildpack: https://github.com/mars/heroku-nextjs.git
remote: -----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://github.com/mars/heroku-nextjs.git
remote:        bash: /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/cc998aa50faebde1ea66717737aec22c884e4936/bin/detect: No such file or directory
remote:
remote:        More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
```

It says `App not compatible with buildpack`.

This is not a buildpack:
https://github.com/mars/heroku-nextjs

These are buildpacks:
https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs

You can ignore this buildpack. It does nothing.
https://github.com/ryanbahniuk/nextjs-buildpack

Read how buildpacks work here:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks

Comment: ... that's not confusing at all. I'm aware of how buildpacks work, and the github confused the heck out of me.  I didn't see any mention of using the 2 buildpacks in the Readme or anything.  Regardless, everything's good to go as expected.  Thank you!

Comment: If you added this buildpack (https://github.com/ryanbahniuk/nextjs-buildpack/blob/master/bin/compile) just to run `next build` it was uncessary to have 2 buildpacks. It would have been suffice to extend your `npm build` script inside `package.json`. See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#customizing-the-build-process